# command that organize the index per page

Tags: makeindex

How can I organize the index by page number? When I do my index first appears the last command I made (`\index {key}`) and then it gets all disorganized. Is there no command that automatically organizes me the index per page?[image]

Comment: Do you mean one index at the end of the document, sorted by page number, rather than by page? Usually, the purpose of the index is to allow you to search a word or term and then to find the page number where it occurs. That's the reason they are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Or are you confusing the Index with the Table of Contents, as in Portuguese the Table of Contents is also called Indice?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Sorry, yes in portuguese is called index. I want a table of contents at the beginning of the document organized by the page number in ascending order. How can I make my table of contents?

Comment: I have a language question, so maybe off-topic: Why do you have 'procedimento' in singular and 'experimentais' in plural?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum "Procedimento" is singular but my subject in sentence is "montagem e procedimento" and both of them are "experimentais". Needless to say "montagem experimental e procedimento experimental". It's more easy.

Answer (score 2):

The Table of Contents is made from the `\chapter`, `\section` etc. titles.

So you would say for example:

```
\chapter{Descrição da montagem...}
```

or

```
\section{Descrição da montagem...}
```

etc. depending on whether this is an article, report or book (or any other document class).
And then in the beginning of the document, you use

```
\tableofcontents
```

You would have to run LateX at least twice.